# ajax help, page doesnt load request for some reason

Tags: javascript, ajax

For some reason my page wont load the ajax data? Can anyone see what the problem is? I am correctly calling the js script into my html but when i load the html page it goes to the alert and says 'There was a problem with the request'.
This is an old school code that i just discovered from a long time ago and I still cant solve the problem to it. Can anyone identify what the problem is?
Thanks

```
// set a global httpRequest object

 var httpRequest;

 // TODO: when the page (window) has loaded, make a
 // request for page 1
 window.onload=function(){
 makeRequest(1);
}

 function makeRequest(pageNum) {

// TODO: create a variable "url" to store the request to 
// the current pageNum, ie:
//
// "http://reqres.in/api/users?page=1" // for page 1
// "http://reqres.in/api/users?page=2" // for page 2
// etc...
var url="http://reqres.in/api/users?page==" + pageNum;





// make an HTTP request object

httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

// show an alert if we were unable to make an XMLHttpRequest object

if (!httpRequest) {
    alert('Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
    return false;
}

// execute the "showContents" function when
// the httprequest.onreadystatechange event is fired

httpRequest.onreadystatechange = showContents;

// open a asynchronous HTTP (GET) request with the specified url

httpRequest.open('GET', url, true);

// send the request

httpRequest.send();
}

// the function that handles the server response

function showContents() {

  //  check for response state
  //  0      The request is not initialized
  //  1      The request has been set up
 //  2      The request has been sent
 //  3      The request is in process
 //  4      The request is complete

if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
    // check the response code
    if (httpRequest.status === 200) { // The request has succeeded
    // Javascript function JSON.parse to parse JSON data
        var jsData = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);

        // TODO: use the jsData object to populate the correct
        // table cells, ie <tr><td>...</td></tr>
        // in the <tbody> element with id="data"

        //var tbody=document.querySelector(#data);



        for(var i=0;i<jsData.data.length;i++)
        {

            console.log("ID: " + jsData.data[i].id);
            console.log("First Name: " +js.Data.data[i].first_name);
            console.log("Last Name: " +js.Data.data[i].last_name);
            console.log("Avatar: " +js.Data.data[i].avatar);
        }

        // TODO: remove the class "active" from all elements with the class "pgbtn"
        for(var i=0;i<jsData.data.length;i++)
        {
        document.getElementById(data[i]).classList.remove(pgbtn);
        }



        // TODO: add the class "active" to the button corresponding to the active page, ie:
        //
        // if jsData.page is 1, add the class "active" to button element with id pgbtn1
        // if jsData.page is 2, add the class "active" to button element with id pgbtn2
        // etc...

    } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
    }
}
}
```

Comment: why don't you do a `console.log(httpReqwuest.status);` so you can see what response code you are getting. Put it right after the `if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) { line`.

Comment: Your page loaded, but the response code is something other than a 200. There could be many reasons why. You can look at the standard response codes here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: var url="http://reqres.in/api/users?page==" + pageNum; -- why is there double equals after page?

Comment: When I try the URL from my browser, I am getting a 301 which is a permanently moved. The new url is `https://reqres.in/api/users?page==`. Notice the 'https' not 'http' that means the page was moved, and the old URL is telling you to go to a new location.

Comment: Are you loading the data from reqres.in or a different domain? Could it be a Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue?